# How can I make my ActionClass return a JSON object while it is implementing SessionAware

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, struts2

I have an Action class that I use with ajax which returns a JSON object. At first I used a constant value. I decided however to use a session Object:

```
public class ViewFlightHistoryAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7325894105057499195L;
    private String viewOption;
    private List<UserBooking> bookingsList;
//  private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        bookingsList = getBookingsList(viewOption);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private List<UserBooking> getBookingsList(String viewOption) throws Exception {
//      Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        Customer customer = (Customer) sessionMap.get("customer");
        BookingManager bookingManager = new BookingManager();
        List<UserBooking> userBookingsList  = new LinkedList<UserBooking>();
        String previousFlights = "Previous Flights";
        String currentFlights = "Current Flights";


        if (previousFlights.equalsIgnoreCase(viewOption)) {
            // Replace parameter with session user's ID
            userBookingsList = bookingManager.getPreviousBookingsList(customer.getCustomerID());
        } else if (currentFlights.equalsIgnoreCase(viewOption)) {
            userBookingsList = bookingManager.getCurrentBookingsList(customer.getCustomerID());
        }

        return userBookingsList;
    }

    public String getViewOption() {
        return viewOption;
    }

    public void setViewOption(String viewOption) {
        this.viewOption = viewOption;
    }

    public List<UserBooking> getBookingsList() {
        return bookingsList;
    }

    public void setBookingsList(List<UserBooking> bookingsList) {
        this.bookingsList = bookingsList;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> sessionMap) {
        this.sessionMap = sessionMap;
    }

}
```

This is my jQuery for ajax:

```
function viewFlightsWithAjax($viewOption) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"viewFlightHistory",
        async:true,
        data: {viewOption: $viewOption},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(jsonObject) {
            var bookingsList = jsonObject.bookingsList;
            for (var i = 0; i < bookingsList.length; i++) {
                var booking = bookingsList[i]; 
                var bookingID = booking.bookingID; 
                var bookingFlightDate = booking.flightDate; 
                bookingFlightDate = toLocaleDate(bookingFlightDate);
                var bookingOrigin = booking.origin; 
                var bookingDestination = booking.destination; 

                var bookingRow = "<tr>" 
                                + "<td>" + bookingID + "</td>"  
                                + "<td>" + bookingFlightDate + "</td>"
                                + "<td>" + bookingOrigin + "</td>"
                                + "<td>" + bookingDestination + "</td>"
                                + "<td>Receipt#</td>"
                                + "<td>Itenerary Details</td>"
                                + "</tr>";
                $("#bookingTable tbody").append(bookingRow);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Anyway my problem is that when I start implementing SessionAware and make use of the session object then it doesn't work anymore. I debugged it and the bookingsList attribute does retrieve the value it just doesn't return it. In my struts.xml, I excluded sessionMap and viewOption yet it still doesn't seem to be returning a JSON value. How can I retrieve the JSON object?

EDIT: I used this interceptor instead:

```
package com.bootcamp.skyjuander.system.interceptors;

import java.util.Map;

import com.bootcamp.skyjuander.service.user.beans.Customer;
import com.bootcamp.skyjuander.system.actions.ViewFlightHistoryAction;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;

public class ViewFlightHistoryInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9003400922950846927L;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        ViewFlightHistoryAction action = (ViewFlightHistoryAction) invocation.getAction();
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        // Customer customer
        Customer sessionCustomer = (Customer) sessionMap.get("customer");

        action.setCustomer(sessionCustomer);


        String result = invocation.invoke();

        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which the real problem is (or was), but it's sure it resides in your struts.xml configuration. You need to either parameterize better your json result, or configure differently your interceptor stack. BTW you seems to have found another route, so good for you. I suggest to check for action instanceOf CustomerAware inside the interceptor, just to be sure it wouldn't break if applied (for any reason, or by mistake) to actions not treating customers

Comment: Interceptor seems like a wrong place to do that. Overall, not very clear what problem do you have.